# NetBeans emits message 'command line is too long'

Tags: java, command-line, netbeans, cmd

I try to run my Java project and NetBeans reports that command line is too long.

Command line length is about 9900 chars long.

How this could be fixed?

I Use Vista 32 OS, NetBeans 6.9.1, jdk1.6.0_12

**UPDATE:**

It looks like this is connected with exec-maven-plugin (http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189137)

Comment: If it is that, then: `The above mentioned problem is fixed in the versions 2+ of the exec-maven-plugin. It could be that a simple update would fix the problem.`

Comment: @masher this does not help because of http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188864. And Netbeans 7.0 is M2 only.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here - you must have a big classpath like I do.  I wish the bug was higher than P3 so they'd patch it.

Easiest way to fix is to right click your project, choose Properties, then click Actions, scroll through the actions and find Run File via main() (or whatever action you're doing).  Once you click that, you'll see that indeed it is using the 1.1.1 version of the maven exec plugin which has this bug.  Just change the 1.1.1 to 1.2.  Unfortunately, I think you'll have to do this for each project you run code from and for each action you use (run project, run via main, debug, etc).  Hopefully someone knows a way to change this globally.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473

There is an explanation and ideas for workarounds...

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with a maven Spring Boot based Java project and the solution for that case was to set fork to false in the Spring Boot plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <fork>false</fork>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I had the spring-boot-maven-plugin already in the project but I added the part below:

```
    <configuration>
        <fork>false</fork>
    </configuration>
```

This is due to a change in Spring Boot to making forking the default.